# 2 button for 2 column of checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, checkbox

I´m working with ASP classic, and I already have a button on my page that select
  all  ch eckboxes, but when I try to make another button, this new "Button2" select all
  checkboxes, I need that button1 ckeck the first column and the button2 chek the 2nd.
  column.
  Thanks in advance.
  [image]

Here is the HTML for button2 "Todos sin sup":

```
<td>
<td align="right" colspan="10"><input type="button"
    name="btn_seleccionar_todo_sin_sup"  value="Todos sin sup" onclick="javascript:marcar
    (this.form);">
</td>   
</td>
```

The Javascript function:

```
function marcar()
{
    var aa= document.getElementById('entregas');
    if (checked == false)
    {
        checked = true
    }
    else
    {
        checked = false
    }
    for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
    {
        aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? (And in the mean time a suggestion about your existing code: you can replace your current if/else block with `checked = !checked;`)

Comment: It is convention to put `;` after assignment statements in Javascript. That means you should have a `;` after `checked = true` and `checked = false`.

Comment: thanks @nnnnnn I´m stuck in the button not in the function, in fact I already use that function, my problem is that the 2 buttons select all checkboxes in the page, but I need that the button1 check just column1 and button2 check column2.

Comment: @Alex W I´m stuck in the button not in the function, in fact I already use that function, my problem is that the 2 buttons select all checkboxes in the page, but I need that the button1 check just column1 and button2 check column2.

Comment: @suely Can you show the HTML for the checkboxes?

Comment: @AlexW I will copy/paste all code, wait a few minutes please.

Comment: @AlexW I think that is the same code for the button1, my problem is that the button2 check all boxes, but I need that the button1(Todos) check the column1(Traspasar) and the button2(Todos sin sup) check the columm2(Sin Supervision), thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *all* of the checkboxes are inside of a container with an id called "entregas."

When your `for` loop iterates through the element with `id="entregas"` it stops at `aa.elements.length`, so you will wrap only the checkboxes you want checked for button 1 in an element with `id="entregas"` and then wrap only the checkboxes that you want to be checked for button 2 in another element with a different, for example `id="entregas2"`.  Then create a new function called, for example `marcar2()`.

Change this line in `marcar2()`:

```
var aa = document.getElementById('entregas2');
```

Then use this HTML for button 2:

```
<input type="button" id="entregas2" value="Button 2" onclick="javascript:marcar2()" />
```